# Alternate API on google cloud for NLP

Tags: text, nlp, speech-recognition, speech

Is there a Nexidia , Aurix alternate API on google cloud for phonetic speedAnalytics on calls? Somewhat like NLP for TextAnalytics

Comment: What did you mean by all those @ and #

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. I have removed it.